# Swift - how can I make a function that requests an Int, and uses it to select an item from an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm learning about arrays and functions, and I'm trying to make a function like this:

1. request a number (let's say we input 1)
2. Use that number to select the position of the item in an array ( ["a","b","c","d","e"])
3. print that array item (it would print "b")

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
func randomLetter(position: Int) {
   let alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
   print (alpha[\(position)])
}

randomLetter(position: 1)
```

Comment: You just need to use `print(alpha[position])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just using wrong syntax. In order to access an element with index "position" in an array of name "alpha", you have to write just

```
alpha[position]
```

Once you access it you can print it directly:

```
print(alpha[position])
```

or use string interpolation syntax to insert it in a message:

```
print("This is your value \(alpha[position])")
```

Hence, the code for your complete function could be:

```
func randomLetter(position: Int){
    let alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
    print (alpha[position])
}
```

Comment: I would add that if you type the original code in Xcode you will have an error : "Ambiguous subscript with base type '[String]' and index type 'WritableKeyPath<_, _>'"
"String interpolation can only appear inside a string literal"
The second part is the most important. 
\() is used to "interpolate" a string, meaning to compose a string from a string literal "here is a string literal" and a variable that will be converted to string.

Comment: I would also add some good practices : 
format the code with the right indentation (space at the beginning of a line in a function) 
And a name that reflect what the function actually does.
Here for exemple your function can be named : func printLetterAt(position:Int)

Comment: Amazing ! thank you! How can I now add a range to position to limit the number input from 0 to 4?